# Add a link to the website

Tags: bibliographies, links, hyperlink

I want to add a  link to the website in the references of my paper without the link is appear.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}         
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue}
% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
 \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
  \newtheorem{definitions}{Definitions}[section]
  \newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
 \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
 \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
 \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
 \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
 \newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
 \numberwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}
\section{1}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{alger}{J. Agler:} {A disconjugacy theorem for Toeplitz operators,} Amer. J. Math. 112(1) (1990) 1-14. \url{http://refhub.elsevier.com/S0024-3795(17)30633-X/bib61s1}.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I would like to get like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but are you looking for something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}         
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue}

\begin{document}
\section{1}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{alger} \href{http://refhub.elsevier.com/S0024-3795(17)30633-X/bib61s1}{  {J. Agler:} {A disconjugacy theorem for Toeplitz operators,} Amer. J. Math. 112(1) (1990) 1-14.}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Student You're welcome! Probably a matter of personal taste, but I find it strange to place the year between volumne/issue and page numbers.

Comment: Thnak you for your comment but it's only a test.